# How to use angular animations to always move it in one direction?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I am trying to use angular animations to move the element to left for `20px` when the button is clicked. It's easy to do, but I can't accomplish to move the element when the button clicked again, where the element had to move another `20px` to left. And continue moving left whenever the button is clicked. Here is my current animation.

```
const animations = [
  trigger('slide', [
    state('left', style({ transform: 'translateX(-20px)' })),
    transition('* => *', animate(300))
  ])
];
```

---

```
<div [@slide]="direction"></div>
```

---

```
onMove() {
  this.direction = 'left';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can't do such a thing without running this kind of animation programmatically, because at the animation start moment you can't set current/new translateX position and continue moving on... But if you do this programmatically, you could set current position:

lets set visible style:

```
.moving-left {
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

some html:

```
<div class="moving-left" #moveLeft></div>
<button (click)="onMove(moveLeft)"> Move Left </button>
```

and typescript: (animationBuilder: AnimationBuilder imported from '@angular/animations')

```
left = 0;
onMove(element: any) {
  const animation = this.animationBuilder.build([
    style({
      transform: `translateX(-${this.left}px)`
    }),
    animate(300, style({
      transform: `translateX(-${this.left + 20}px)`
    }))
  ]);

  const player = animation.create(element);
  player.play();
  this.left += 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `AnimationBuilder`. I'll try this